# Create node that contains updated value by time

Tags: bash

My question contains 2 separated parts:

- How to create node (mb mknod) that contains value which I wonna update by time and how to update it
- Or how to execute code on cat command on some file

My history:
I want to use ncpufreq, but in new kernels destination of temp file was changed and now it in `/sys/class/thermal` but was in `/proc/acpi/`. In addition format of output also changed and now I should divide value in `/sys/class/thermal` by 1000 and point file in `/etc/ncpufreq.conf`
I created sh script that in loop just read input from `/sys/class/thermal`, divide it and output in another file. But it looks ugly, better was if I has only one file.
And here is my questions, how to achive it:

1. create node similar to nodes in /sys/class with some logic or
2. when some code use `cat /file` return execution response

Also sometimes I've got (in the same time of access):

> Oct 30 21:26:37 bee ncpufreqd[12160]: failed to read "/home/jiojiajiu/temp_output" (Bad file descriptor)
>   Oct 30 21:26:37 bee ncpufreqd[12160]: can't read ACPI temperature, terminating
>   Oct 30 21:26:37 bee ncpufreqd[12160]: ncpufreqd terminated

Comment: What is wrong with using the "new" value?